# где нужен inner?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Когда пишешь запрос с эквисоединением во фразе INNER JOIN можно опустить INNER. Но бывают такие случаи где, не указав INNER, запрос может быть выполнен не правильно. Объясните что это за случаи?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что бывают такие случаи?

Comment: Таких случаев не бывает. слово inner абсолютно не нужно

Comment: @Mike, но только не в MySQL :-D

Comment: @Grundy Почему ? MySQL спокойно без него обходится. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html Выдержка: _In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents ..._

Comment: @Mike, это да, сначала посмотрел [тут](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html) - без указания считается как CROSS, потом посмотрел тут: [In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) то есть в mysql CROSS и INNER одно и то же, и разницы нет указывать или нет, но вообще по стандарту это разные вещи :)

Answer (score 2):

В [справке по JOIN в MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) указано следующее:

> In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise.

> В MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN и INNER JOIN синтаксически эквивалентны (каждый из них может использоваться вместо любого другого). В стандарте SQL они не эквивалентны. INNER JOIN используется вместе с ON, а CROSS JOIN в противном случае.

---

То есть в MySQL CROSS JOIN и INNER JOIN и просто JOIN – это одно и то же, и нет разницы что использовать.